# Finding the domain of a composition of functions where one function is given in terms of y and the other in terms of x.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

For a math assignment I was assigned by my professor, I've been asked to find the domain of a composition of the following functions.

$f(y) =\frac{4}{y - 2}$

$g(x) =\frac{5}{3x - 1}$

I know that the domain of $f(y)$ is all real numbers excluding $y = 2$ and that the domain of $g(x)$ is all real numbers excluding x = 1/3. As such, it makes sense to me that a composition of the two functions should be restricted in the same way, such that the input to $g(x)$ cannot be $1/3$ (because $g(1/3)$ is undefined) and cannot cause $g(x) = 2$ (because $f(2)$ is undefined). When trying to graph a composition of these two functions, however, I get a function that is defined at $1/3$ (desmos.com shows $f(g(1/3)) = 0)$. Can anyone help me wrap my head around this? Am I going about finding a composition the wrong way?

Comment: The domain of composition is the intersection of domains of $f$ and $g$ so it will not be defined at $1 \over 3$

Comment: @Vasya No, it is not the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the composition $ f\circ g$ is $$D_{f(g)}=$$

$$\{x\in \Bbb R \;:\; x\in D_g \; and\; g(x)\in D_f\}$$

Or, in other equivalent way

Let $ x\in \Bbb R$. Then

$$x\in D_{f(g)}\iff $$
$$x\in D_g \; and \; g(x)\in D_f$$

So, in your example, as you said

$$x\in D_{f(g)}\iff $$
$$x\ne \frac 13\; and\; g(x)\ne 2$$

$$\iff x\ne \frac 13\; and \; \frac{5}{3x-1}\ne 2$$

$$\iff x\in \Bbb R\backslash \{\frac 13,\frac 76\}$$

Comment: To continue off of this answer, which I think makes sense; why does Desmos.com show the graph of this composition of functions as being defined for x=1/3? Is this an error in the calculator itself?

Comment: We cannot compute $ g(1/3)$ so we cannot get $f(g(1/3)$. The desmos made a mistake and it doesn't know that it did.

Comment: Thank you for your timely response and your thorough explanation.